# MVC MS Chart Export to PNG C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mschart

I am trying to export MS Chart that is generated in c#, I was successful in addining it to itextsharp PDF using

```
....
 var image = Image.GetInstance(ChartPng(list, propertyList, displayNames));
.....
```

The chart is saved in the buffer

```
 using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chart.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                return chartimage.GetBuffer();
            }
```

I was able to open it in the browser, using:

```
 return File(ChartPng(list, propertyList, displayNames), "image/png");
```

How I can make it as download rather than saving it to a particular disk, any suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881248/mvc-open-pdf-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to write it directly to the Response stream, you can look at my answer here:

[How to refresh asp.net charts in MVC using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247315/how-to-refresh-asp-net-charts-in-mvc-using-jquery/2293745#2293745)

**Edit:**

To prompt the user to download the file instead, use the FileContentResult.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried the proposed solution; the chart open in the browser.

Comment: I misread your question, I thought that was what you wanted. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use: var image = Image.GetInstance(Chart(list, propertyList, displayNames));
            return FileResult(image, "image/png");.  Got this error:System.Web.Mvc.FileResult' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: I believe there is an overload on File that takes a `string filename`. That should prompt for the download. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name.